# PHP preg_replace ignoring \h and \v flags

Tags: php, regex, pcre

preg_replace and preg_match are ignoring \h (horizontal whitespace) and \v (vertical whitespace) flags, and I can't figure out why.

```
$text = preg_replace('/[\h]+/', ' ', $text);
```

That line should replace any string of consecutive horizontal whitespace characters with a single space. Instead, it is replacing the letter 'h'.

I have PCRE 6.6 installed. I'm aware of [:blank:] as a replacement for \h but I can't find any alternative for \v (and of course I'd prefer to just figure out why these are not working instead of replacing them with something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported in your version of PCRE.

http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt

The changelog says `\h` has been added in version 7.2

Comment: Okay thanks. I had misread the PCRE documentation where it said \h and \v were added in *Perl* 5.10, which I misread as PCRE 5.10

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, horizontal whitespace is just space and tab. So `[ \t]`

Comment: It may be helpful but it doesn't attempt to answer the question.  It would be better placed as a comment.